# Angular Js stuck in inserting the array values after sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello guys i am stuck in angular js.
What i have to do is to show the steps of selectionSort and the code i made is

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var arraymain = [];

myApp.controller('myController',function($scope) {
    $scope.array2 = [];
    $scope.selectionSort = function(list) {
    n=list.length;
    temp2 = list;
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) { //need to do n-2 passes
        i_min=i;
        //finding mining index
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){//ith position: elements from i till n-1 candidates
            if(temp2[j]<temp2[i_min]) 
                i_min=j; //update the index of minimim element
        }
        temp=temp2[i];
        temp2[i]=temp2[i_min];
        temp2[i_min]=temp;
        alert(temp); //It shows as needed
                    $scope.array2.push(temp2); //Here i am having problem it saves the sorted final array i.e the last every time of loop but i want to save current array on every outer loop execution                       
    }
    return list;

    $scope.selectionSort([3,2,3,4,5,1,2]);
    console.log($scope.array2[0]);
    console.log($scope.array2[1]);
    console.log($scope.array2[2]);
});
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you need to do. I'm pretty sure you've got a real mess on your hands beyond your main problem, and using Angular is only making it worse.

If your goal is to `console.log` the state of the array at each step of the `selectionSort` outer loop, then you need to run `console.log` at the bottom of each loop.

The first thing that looks fishy suspicious is:

```
$scope.array2.push(temp2);
```

If you run `console.log(array2)` at each step of the loop as I suggested, you need this line to be instead:

```
$scope.array2 = temp2;
```

That way, you overwrite `array2`, which holds the state of the array at each iteration of the `for` loop. Then you log it. Appending each state to a larger array, and then running console.log on each item in that array is not the best way to do this.

But, I'm not sure that's what your problem is.

Comment: Buddy i want to save the array values because later i have to put animations on that so i want to push the values in array and then i will use ng repeat and nganimate to complete. In a nut shell i have to show the animated working of selection sort in js and i guess angular is the smallest solution